# R - NiceHash API - HMAC signing issue?

Tags: r, api, curl, get

[This is a duplicate post from NiceHash's [GitHub](https://github.com/nicehash/rest-clients-demo/issues/39) in an attempt to broaden the audience. If I find a solution, at least others will also be able to see it in more places too]

Hi all,

I'm a newbie and the only language I know a little of is R.

I've managed to get a number of other APIs working under R using syntax like this:

```
  # Account Stats
  response <- httr::GET( 
    url = "https://API_URL_GOES_HERE", 
  )
```

I think I've got the gist of the syntax for R, but I'm having problems with hashing the Secret Key.

My API key / secret works with the "Try it out" link [here](https://www.nicehash.com/docs/rest/get-main-api-v2-accounting-hashpowerEarnings-currency).

But I get the usual invalid / 2000 error when passing my hashed secret key via the API.

Here's how I'm trying to generate the hashed secret key:

```
input <- paste0(APIKey," ", XTime," ", XNonce," "," ", OrgID," ", " ", "GET"," ", "/main/api/v2/accounting/accounts2", " ")
# Needs hashed?
APISecret <- hmac(input, "My_Secret_Key", "sha256")
XAuth <- paste0(APIKey, ":", APISecret)
```

And here's my API call:

```
# Account Stats
response<- httr::GET( 
  url = "https://api2.nicehash.com/main/api/v2/accounting/accounts2", 
  httr::add_headers(
    `X-Time` = XTime,
    `X-Nonce` = XNonce,
    `X-Organization-Id` = OrgID,
    #`X-Request-Id` = XNonce,
    `X-Auth`= XAuth,
    `Content-Type` = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  )
)
```

My thoughts are:

1. input is not correctly formatted
2. HMAC() isn't generating what NiceHash expects
3. My GET() isn't structured quite right

Any ideas?

EDIT - Link [here](https://www.nicehash.com/docs/) explains how the input is supposed to be structured.

EDIT - Link [here](https://github.com/nicehash/rest-clients-demo) is examples in other languages, which I can't fully translate to R. The code I've shown above is my attempt.

UPDATE - OK, I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the hashing of the input string.

Using this as input:

```
4ebd366d-76f4-4400-a3b6-e51515d054d6 ⊠ 1543597115712 ⊠ 9675d0f8-1325-484b-9594-c9d6d3268890 ⊠ ⊠ da41b3bc-3d0b-4226-b7ea-aee73f94a518 ⊠ ⊠ GET ⊠ /main/api/v2/hashpower/orderBook ⊠ algorithm=X16R&page=0&size=100
```

The following string:

```
fd8a1652-728b-42fe-82b8-f623e56da8850750f5bf-ce66-4ca7-8b84-93651abc723b
```

when hashed should lead to:

```
21e6a16f6eb34ac476d59f969f548b47fffe3fea318d9c99e77fc710d2fed798
```

But I cannot get that as output. I've no idea what to use in place of ⊠ when forming the input. Other language examples use "\x00", but R just errors with:

```
Error: nul character not allowed (line 1)
```

Comment: I don't know, I think this might be viewed as a `spam-ish` kind of question.

Comment: Apologies if that's the case.

As far as I understand it, I'm asking for help with how to structure / syntax a coding query and my feeling is it's something code-related, possibly with zero byte characters in my creation of the input to hash my secret key?

There are examples of how it's done correctly in other languages at NiceHash's [GitHub](https://github.com/nicehash/rest-clients-demo) but I don't know any of them or how I can translate them to R.

General example [here](https://www.nicehash.com/docs/), but again, I'm too inexperienced with R to know how to get it working

Comment: I also try to "give back" to the community by posting / sharing things. For example, I had a similar problem trying to get an IG API working in R. When I figured out a basic enough example, I created a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/JimboMahoney/rIG) so that others might find it too. I'll do the same with this if I get it working.